# Why does the webcam on my Dell SX2210 go all green and purple?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, webcam

I'm using an aluminium unibody MacBook (pre unibody 13" MacBook Pro) running 10.6.7 with a Dell SX2210 external monitor. The monitor has a built in webcam and USB hub. When I try to use the webcam with my Mac I often a very strange looking green and purple picture, as shown below.

The problem isn't specific to just one app as it's the same in both Photo Booth and Skype. Also the iSight built into my laptop works just fine.

The strange thing is that for a couple of minutes after plugging in the USB cable the picture is fine, but then it starts degrading - at first just a couple of of spots of green show up, and then it gradually spreads.

I've had the monitor for nearly 2 years now and it definitely didn't do this when I first got it. However recently I've been wanting to use Skype more and found that it's doing this.

I didn't install any drivers for it so I guess it's just using standard USB video drivers built into OS X.

I don't have easy access to another Mac or PC to try this with but I have tried a different USB cable, to no avail.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions!

[Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2bDv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issue with the camera - is the monitor still in warranty? Definitely try it with another computer if at all possible.

Comment: Sadly I don't think it's in warranty any more. Will try to find another computer to test it with.